# Segmentation fault in c related to strcat

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation error when I try to run my code, and I've narrowed it down to this block, but I am not sure why:

```
string myNewKey = "";

if (keylength < length){
    int myValue = ((length - keylength) / keylength) + 1;

    for (int i=0; i < myValue; i++)
        myNewKey = strcat(key, myNewKey);  
}

printf("%s", myNewKey);
```

I know it has something to do with the `strcat`, but I don't know exactly what.

Just to clarify. This is NOT for school or work. I am just trying to learn C on my own, and I am following the Harvard open course lectures for the introductory programming class.

Comment: is this for homework or work?

Comment: What is "string" and where it is defined?

Comment: just take any book about C++ and read, read, read.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that you are mixing C and C++ in incompatible ways.

Comment: Also, when you get a segmentation fault, or any other crash, the first thing you should do is to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate the exact location of the crash, and let you examine variables to see what might have cause the crash.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/).  Your question is tagged C; is that correct, or did you really mean C++?  If you mean C++, my answer is somewhat tangential (but there's a deleted answer that is spot on).  I trusted your tag.  (I note from your profile that you've asked no C++ questions, but you have asked one other C question.)

Comment: Are you certain this is C and not C++, do you have `using std` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have a standard type called `string`, and you've not shown us how you've defined it.

However, we can make a guess that it is similar to:

```
char *myNewKey = "";

if (keylength < length)
{
  int myValue = ((length - keylength) / keylength) + 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < myValue; i++)
      myNewKey = strcat(key, myNewKey);
}

printf("%s", myNewKey);
```

Even without seeing the declaration of `key`, we can see trouble coming.  Let's assume that you have:

```
char key[100] = "a";
```

If you iterate the loop often enough (again, we don't have enough information to be sure what you're up to — please brush up on what constitutes a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/)), then you'll overflow the buffer sooner or later, and that will lead to trouble and *may* cause a segmentation fault.

If `key` is also a `string` like my hypothesized `myNewKey`, then you have all sorts of space allocation problems, plus you could be writing to read-only memory (a good way of getting a segmentation fault and core dump).

For other definitions of `string`, `key` and `myNewKey` (not to mention `length` and `keylength`), there are other ways of running into problems.

You should probably add a newline to the end of the format string (`"%s\n"`) in the `printf()` statement.  Without it, you're not guaranteed too see the output in a timely fashion (even with it, you might not see the output in a timely fashion, but a program running in a terminal window will usually output each line as the newline ending it is written).

Answer (score 2):

With the same hypotesis of Jonathan:

strcat already makes the append and modifies key, then it returns a pointer to key.
Are you aware of that?

This means that at the second step you get the equivalent of strcat(key,key) that could be good enough to cause a segmentation fault (it depends on the strcat implementation).

If the strcat(key,key) does not cause the fault, the following will happen.

Staring key = "A" and a myvalue of 5 you would get the following steps:

1. key = "A", myNewKey = "A"
2. key = "AA", myNewKey = "AA"
3. key = "AAAA", myNewKey = "AAAA"
4. key = "AAAAAAAA", myNewKey = "AAAAAAAAA"
5. key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", myNewKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

As you can se at each step the length of the two strings would grow exponentially. I don't think that's what you meant to do.

Comment: That is actually what I meant to do. It's hard to explain here, but I need to keep concatenating the string to itself for a certain number of times.

Comment: Since everytime newKey and key are the same pointer it does not make sense to have two variables for them. Anyway, strcat(key,key) is bad. In strcat source and destination must not overlap. It might be that it works (did not try, it might also be the cause of the segmentation fault) but it's implementation dependent of the strcat.